# Firebug not showing Javascript errors for Rails applications

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

I have a Rails application, and when I have Javascript errors they are not showing in the Firebug console. I have 'Show javascript errors' and 'Show javascript warnings' selected.

When I insert javascript errors in a basic html file, the errors show as expected.

In the javascript of the Rails app, it only shows errors in rare cases.
For example i can insert nonsense like:

dfghaefb;

and no error is shown in Firebug. But if i insert a space in there Firebug does show the error:

dfgh aefb;

Any ideas? This is driving me nuts.

**UPDATE:**
Pumbaa80 was right, it's syntax vs runtime.

So I set up onerror:

```
onerror=errorHandler;
var error="";

 function errorHandler(errMessage,url,line){
  error="There is an error at this page.\n";
  error+="Error: " + errMessage+ "\n";
  error+="URL: " + url + "\n";
  error+="Line: " + line + "\n\n";
  error+="Click OK to continue viewing this page,\n";
  alert(error);
  return true;
 }

And I have a method with an error:

function initForm() {
    asdfs;
}
```

And it works when I call it outside of a method:

```
initForm();
```

but not in this case:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {

    initForm();
});
```

Why is that?

Comment: Well, `dfghaefb;` is not an error :-)

Comment: it is -- it's not defined. it shows as an error in my html page.

Comment: oh well durr, you're right.  Well, Firefox in general can be pretty cavalier about ignoring/hiding exceptions at parse time. I don't know whether Firebug has any impact on that, but it's not a Rails thing because it happens to me all the time and I don't use Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dfghaefb;
```

produces a run-time error. Those errors may be suppressed by putting an `onerror` handler on the `window` or by trapping them in a `try/catch` in some way. In that case, Firebug won't show anything.

In contrast,

```
dfgh aefb;
```

is a syntax error, which is shown in the error console, regardless of `try/catch` and `onerror`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you let the page load completely? I have a rails app running in front of me right now with firebug on and i entered dfghaefb; and yes it does throw an error!

```
 ReferenceError: dfghaefb is not defined {  message="dfghaefb is not defined",  more...}
```

Running Firefox 3.6.3, Firebug 1.5.3 and MacOSX 10.5.6 :)

Answer (score 0):

This may appear to be obvious, but be sure you wrap your inline JS using

```
<script type="text/javascript"> code </script>
```

Otherwise FireBug won't look at it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same, it wasn't showing anything and it was driving me crazy for ages, even if i had "Show javascript errors" in the console tab selected, it seems that it started working after I did "Enable all panels".

Answer (score -1):

These kinds of problems cannot be answered without a test case.